# Which option will let avconv convert video to images starting from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: avconv

I need to convert a video to images. One requirement is that the index starts from 0.  The command below is executed.

```
avconv -i INPUT %04d.png
```

However, the resulting image index starts from 0001.png, rather than 0000.png.

Which option will designate the starting number?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-start_number` switch:

```
avconv -start_number 0 -i '%04d.png' -qmax 16 out.mp4
```

Comment: I noticed that it is important to put `-start_number` option before `-i`